# F# use keyword and recursive functions

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, f#, idisposable, tail-recursion

As far as I understood, the `use` keyword disposes the bound `IDisposable` as soon it is out of scope, so considering this recursive function:

```
let rec AsyncAcceptMessages(client : WebSocket) =
  async {
    let! message = client.AsyncReadMessage
    use reader = new StreamReader(message)
    let s = reader.ReadToEnd()
    printf "%s" <| s
    do! AsyncAcceptMessages client
  }
```

Let's pretend that the compiler does not find a way of using tail recursion, would that `StreamReader`  be disposed after each recursion?

**UPDATE**

Tomas response show me a way of fixing it when you actually expect something back, but what if you are expecting nothing? like in this example with the `StreamWriter`:

```
let rec AsyncAcceptMessages(client : WebSocket) =
  async {
    let! message = client.AsyncReadMessage
    if(not(isNull message)) then 
      let s = 
        use reader = new StreamReader(message)
        reader.ReadToEnd()
      use writer = new StreamWriter(client.CreateMessageWriter(WebSocketMessageType.Text), Encoding.UTF8)
      writer.Write s
      printf "%s" <| s
    do! AsyncAcceptMessages client
  }
```

Comment: Regarding your update, you can put the `IDisposable` in a nested scope using `do`. [See gist.](https://gist.github.com/FunctionalFirst/0348951e82335a5add3d)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're saying, the `StreamReader` would only be disposed of *after* the execution returns from the recursive call (i.e. never).

There is another issue, which is that `do!` is not treated as a tail-recursive call, so if you want to create an infinite tail-recursive loop, you need to use `return!` (otherwise your code will be leaking memory).

In this case, you can fix it easily using, because you're not doing any asynchronous operations with the `StreamReader`, so you can just create an ordinary local scope:

```
let rec AsyncAcceptMessages(client : WebSocket) =
  async {
    let! message = client.AsyncReadMessage
    let s = 
      use reader = new StreamReader(message)
      reader.ReadToEnd()
    printf "%s" <| s
    return! AsyncAcceptMessages client
  }
```

If you wanted to call e.g. `AsyncReadToEnd`, then you could do something like:

```
let rec AsyncAcceptMessages(client : WebSocket) =
  async {
    let! message = client.AsyncReadMessage
    let! s =
      async { use reader = new StreamReader(message)
              return! reader.ReadToEnd() }
    printf "%s" <| s
    return! AsyncAcceptMessages client
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way good luck with your book F# Deep Dives, I pre-ordered it last week, I am sure it won't disappoint.